# Unable to capture screenshot greater than screen height

Tags: casperjs, phantomcss

I'm looking to capture a 5000px long screenshot. But after capturing, it only captures content that is equal to the height of my desktop screen height which is 1080px and rest is blank.

`casper.viewport(1024, 5000);`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up your Casper options correctly. Look at their documentation at http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#index-1.

It appears there is a secion on viewport size here http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#viewportsize. From the docs: `PhantomJS ships with a default viewport of 400x300, and CasperJS won’t override it by default.`

Comment: I tried explicitly setting height, for both viewport and image but its still showing blank `casper.captureSelector('./screenshots/build/desktop/main-content-' + currentPage + '.png', '.main-content', {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 1024,
      height: 5000
     });`

Comment: @RahulDagli Have you changed the viewport size in caspers settings

Comment: Here's the viewport height `casper.viewport(1024, 5000);`

Comment: yes, I believe from reading the casper docs you need to explicitly set the viewport dimensions otherwize they will be overridden by PhantomJS. Please try casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 5000} before you call to casper.viewport()

Comment: I tested with other page and it's working there. I think this issue might be related to rendering of the page while capturing the screenshot since the outer scrolling is hidden ie. `body` and `html` and internal scrolling is enabled.